# How to call an executable C file from within the command line while running a different C file?

Tags: c, command-line, interface, executable

I have an executable create program that runs when entering

```
./create -f pathname [linkname]
```

I have a different C program that serves as an interface and requires command line user input without the "./" in the beginning.

How would I call the executable "create" and have it run from the other program?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system() function to run a bash command from C program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int status_val =  system("./program2 args")
```